# Can't be summoned on Old Iron King

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've been trying to help people on Dark Souls 2 with the Iron King boss, but every time I get summoned, when the summoning player enters the mist I immediately get sent back to my world.

**Is Iron King a solo-only fight?**  For what it's worth, I only used the Small White Sign Soapstone so I can get Smooth & Silky Stones.  I am level 125, with Soul Memory of 1,984,871, and am playing on NG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Old Iron King is not a solo-only fight. I have had both phantoms and shades on the fight with me before. Do you receive a message that you are being sent back to your world, or does it immediately disconnect you and send you back? If the former, it is possible that the host has defeated the boss previously (Small White Soapstone allows you to be summoned after the boss has been defeated). When this occurs, phantoms are returned to their world when the host enters the fog.

If that is not the problem, I'm unsure what could be. If it was connection issues, it should have failed to summon you at all.

Comment: It gave me a message, something along the lines of "The host has existed this area.  Returning you to your home world."  It happened after he-- the host-- entered the fog gate for the boss.  And it happened twice on the same host.  Also, I had already defeated Old Iron King, if that matters.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that you have defeated the boss. However, that is the message you will receive if the host has defeated the boss. Did it happen with multiple other hosts? Or just this one?

Comment: I only tried it on just this one host.  So maybe he's defeated the boss already.  But shouldn't the fog gate have been cleared after he defeated the boss?  Like, why would he have been able to enter the fog if he's already defeated the boss?

Comment: If you are alone, the boss fog does disappear. However, if you summon a shade, the fog reappears for exactly this purpose - to serve as a boundary for the shades. I have seen it happen when I summoned a friend as a shade in an area I had already defeated the boss.

Comment: Ah I see. That gives me some better context.  Maybe it was just a one-time incident, and the host had already defeated the boss.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bit late with this reply but A second Pursuer appears where the Smelter demon was and that you can't take a phantom with you into this fight. This may be the reason you where getting unsummoned.